# A doubt on independent events in probability

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

**A article manufactured by a company consists of 3 component A, B, C. These components are manufactured by 3 independent processes. The probability of these components being defective in the process of manufacture are 0.04, 0.03, 0.05 respectively. what is the probability of the assembled article being defective?**

*To answer this question, I thought that P(AnBnC)= P(A).P(B).P(C)= 0.00006 is the answer since these 3 components are independent.*

**So I need help whether the answer is correct or wrong and if its wrong then how to get the correct answer?**

- 

Comment: Your answer is correct. Independence implies exactly that the probability of the intersections of $n$ events is the product of their probabilities.

Comment: @Schach21 That is not correct. The probability of the article being defective is $0.11536$.

Comment: "These components are manufactured by 3 independent processes." This verbiage is intended, by the problem composer, to imply that you do have independent events.

Comment: The probability that the assembled article is defective cannot be less than the probability of one of the components being defective, so the answer is clearly incorrect.

Comment: You want $$1 - \left[(1 - p(A)) \times (1 - p(B)) \times (1 - p(C))\right].$$

Comment: Determine the probability that the assembled article is **not** defective and the compute the complement.

Comment: @user2661923 Your formula is correct, but the first comment is not.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, I didn't check his math.  I have edited my comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'd expect that the product is defective if *any* of the components are defective, not all of them.

Let $D$ be the event the product is defective, then $D = A \cup B \cup C$

So,
$$P(D) = P(A \cup B \cup C) = 1-P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c)=$$
$$1-(1-P(A))(1-P(B))(1-P(C)) =  1-(.96)(.97)(.95) = 11.54\%$$

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the definition of defective article, which is not given clearly in the problem. If the article is defective in case when the three elements are defective the answer is correct. If the article is defective when at least one of the elements is defective the answer is not correct. In this case the formula given by @user2661923 is correct.